# Loop history commands from first to 10 using Bash terminal

Tags: bash, terminal

I'm should use `until` loop to get first 10 commands from history line by line.

Tried something like:

```
counter=0

until [ $counter -gt 10 ]
do
  echo !$counter
  ((counter++))
done
```

But output is `docounter` ten times.

The main issue is how to get inside loop specific line from history.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few simple ways. Try this -

```
 while read -r cmd; do if ((ctr++ < 10)); then echo "$cmd"; fi; done < "$HISTFILE"
```

or

```
history|head -10|mapfile -t h && for c in {0..9}; do echo "${h[c]}"; done
```

## edit

The terminal you are using at [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/linux_terminal_online.php) kinda sucks.

Try it this way, and pay attention to why it matters.

```
history | while read -r cmd; do if ((ctr++ < 10)); then echo "$cmd"; fi; done
```

Specifically, `bash: /tmp/.bash_history: Permission denied`

They are apparently only allowing access to the history file through the `history` program.

Comment: I'm received "The system cannot find the file specified." Maybe there is something different way?

Comment: If you know the filename, try just using that directly. Also, I should have quoted it...done. Might work now. (Best to include the *whole* error message if possible. The problem might have been embedded spaces in the path, for example.)

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I'm use your code in https://www.tutorialspoint.com/linux_terminal_online.php nut it failed

Comment: They apparently do not have a `mapfile`, or decent error reporting...
Do you not have a real terminal? Can you install and use Git Bash?

Comment: This *is* a good exercise in debugging. Be aware of the limitations of your environ and tools so you can adapt and accommodate.

Answer (score 0):

Csh-style history expansion is an interactive feature; it does not work in scripts.

It's looking like you are simply looking for `history $HISTSIZE | head -n 10`

Comment: I sort of expected `history -10` to do that but alas, it does not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately according to task I should to use loop to display history commands line by line.